# Lag on iPhone while using SIOSocket

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, delay

Has anybody ever used SIOSocket? I am experiencing delay in iPhone while using this. App is working fine on iPad though. Any ideas?

Comment: Where exactly. I'm also using SIOSocket. Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: The delay is not consistent. I'm developing a game and experiencing delay in receiving response from the server on iPhone. Have you ever experienced this?